# Why is my playback so slow?

Tags: animation

I just upgraded my computer to have 32 GB of RAM, an RTX 4080 and Ryzen 7 5800X3D and whenever I play my animation in blender while in rendered mode, the frames drop to about 5-6 fps.  I'm a relatively new animator so I know it's not because of my animation having too much data.  Are there some settings I have to change?  I typically render in eevee but am willing to switch to cycles if it provides a better animplayer.  All settings currently are set to default and I'm on blender 2.90.1

Comment: no way to know because you did not provide a blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: well, as first proposal, i wouldn't play the animation in rendered mode, but in viewport shading. This should make it a lot quicker. And then Harry is of course right, without knowing anything you did - how can we tell? You can search here or on google for "blender slow viewport" -> these questions are asked a lot. And you will get "general" answer - but maybe not suitable for you. If you wanna have a suitable answer for you, you should give us all necessary informations - so providing the blend file is (in my opinion) the best way to do that